# Positioning with flex CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create an app-like experience web-app, using HTML, CSS and JS. This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: WebApp View]

I've set the body&html width to 100vw and height to 100vh. Then I went on and set the TopBar height to 40vh while I gave the body the remaining 60vh value.I added three div's to the TopBar(green ones) and gave them these values:

```
display:flex;
position:relative;
flex-direction:column;
```

then went on and gave these values to the first element:

```
width:100%;
align-self:flex-start;
```

,and proceeded with the same ones for the last element except I used *flex-end*;

So everything was looking OK, expect the middle one which was aligning to its uppermost position leaving a huge gap between itself and the last element when the screen was taller (in iPhone 6Plus).

Is there any way I can center it vertically in its container without using position absolute?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. We could help you more effectively if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B Will do as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by using "vmin" as padding units on the middle element in the flex object.